# What is the proper way to render components on SAP Spartacus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

My question is about SAP Spartacus.

I wanted to know which way should be followed while making components:

1)Make components in Hybris, and use it on Spartacus storefront via a REST call.

2)Make components in Angular and use it on app component.Also wanted to know what is the correct way to use it on Spartacus storefront

Answer (score 2):

I would generally go with 2nd option, i.e. create components in Angular and:

1) map them to existing component defined in hybris

2) Use `CMSFlexComponent` with `flexType` in hybris CMS to map it to your Angular component

You can read how to configure CMS component mapping in docs: 
https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/customizing-cms-components/